# PHP Passing an Array to a Function

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

How can I pass an array to a function?

Let's say I have this multi-dimensional array:

```
$TheArray = (
array("Value 1 0","Value 1 1","Value 1 2"),
array("Value 2 0","Value 2 1","Value 2 2"),
array("Value 3 0","Value 3 1","Value 3 2")
);
```

Instead of doing this...

```
for ($i=0; $i<=(count($TheArray)-1); $i++)
{
echo $TheArray[$i][0] . " " . $TheArray[$i][1] . " " . $TheArray[$i][2] . "<br />";
}
```

I want to do this...

```
function DoStuffWithTheArray($SubArr)
{
echo $SubArr[0] . " " . $SubArr[1] . " " . $SubArr[2] . "<br />";
}

for ($i=0; $i<=(count($TheArray)-1); $i++)
{
DoStuffWithTheArray($TheArray[$i]);
}
```

Hopefully, you can tell what I am trying to do, but I do not know how to get it to work. When I do try it the way I want, all the values are empty

Comment: What does *all the values are empty* mean? Do you not get any output?

Comment: Get in the habit of using [`foreach` loops](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for array iteration whenever possible.  In PHP, using an incremental `for` loop is actually not that common for basic iteration.

Comment: Try add `echo 'function called<br/>';` into `function DoStuffWithTheArray` to check if you have called the function

Comment: aren't you missing an `array` at `$TheArray = array(`?

Comment: This works exactly as you have it, except for the missing `array(` keyword.  http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ysz6qT. If that is your issue (blank screen), turn on error reporting. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: A more typical PHP implementation using foreach would look like http://codepad.viper-7.com/iwKAhy. I have not used the function here, but it could be done as well.

Comment: I would replace `$i<=(count($TheArray)-1)` with `$i<count($TheArray)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to learn first how create an array;

```
// instead of this
$TheArray = (...
// you can create an array so
$TheArray = array(...
```

Second, change this style please and see: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($TheArray); $i++)
```

And answer;

```
$array = array(
    array("Value 1 0", "Value 1 1", "Value 1 2"),
    array("Value 2 0", "Value 2 1", "Value 2 2"),
    array("Value 3 0", "Value 3 1", "Value 3 2")
);

function fn($a) {
    print "$a[0], $a[1], $a[1]\n";
}

foreach ($array as $a) fn($a);
```

```
Value 1 0, Value 1 1, Value 1 1
Value 2 0, Value 2 1, Value 2 1
Value 3 0, Value 3 1, Value 3 1
```

Comment: I do know how to create an array. It was a typo on my part. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the array in:

```
function DoStuffWithTheArray($array) {
    $array[0]...$array[n];
}
```

That should work. Does it not?

Comment: This is what the OP is doing with `DoStuffWithTheArray($TheArray[$i])` inside the loop.

Comment: The second example works for me. You do need to make the following correction: `$TheArray = array(...`. But when I past in the array and the second section of code, it works just fine on http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter the content of the array, then you need to pass it by reference:

[Argument passing by Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference)